# Network is unclaimed

Tags: 14.04

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on my computer. But,  the network is unclaimed. I don't have the drive, How can I download the right drive? I don't have wifi, so I can not use the internet or wifi for download.

Comment: Ethernet is usually supported except when newer than the release. Any special reason for 14.04?

Comment: it's my work pc. they installed it. no reason.

Comment: Why don't you try any recent one like 17.04 in a live session?

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and follow the links to How to create a bootable USB stick...

Comment: how should I download the driver? I think my problem will be resolved if I download https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817

Comment: But, I don't know how to download it without using the wifi? is there a specific command?

Comment: That are no magical commands that let you download something without an internet connection. If a driver is required it must be downloaded from somewhere else and since you'd need to do that. do the smart thing instead: Download and install the current Ubuntu.

Comment: I need the internet to download 17.04 ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, of course, as well as to download anything needed like drivers. That IS the point. Since you need to download from somewhere else then do the smart thing.

Comment: If it really an Intel card, then the driver has been included in all recent versions of Ubuntu. Let's identify the card and try to load the driver and see what happens. Please post the result the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3`

Comment: @chili555  the result is: 00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8080:15b7] (rev 31)

Comment: The driver for your device is `e1000e`. Let's load it and see what messages appear. Please run and post the result of: `sudo modprobe e1000e && dmesg | grep -e e100 -e 1f.6`